# How to convert TIMESTAMPS formats to be compatible with Impala

Tags: sql, regex, impala

Here is a sample of my data in CSV format:

```
6/30/2014 23:57,2006,604,131
7/1/2014 0:24,2217,263,143
6/30/2014 23:26,173,3481,134
...
```

I would like to load this CSV file in Impala table and have the first column as "TIMESTAMP":

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(col1 timestamp, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int)
  row format delimited
  fields terminated by ',';

LOAD DATA INPATH '/dataset/data' INTO TABLE my_table;
```

But Impala accepts TIMESTAMPS as the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.sssssssss
```

While my data is:

```
MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM
```

How can I convert my data in the fastest way to be readable by Impala as TIMESTAMPS? I am trying to use `regexp_replace` but was not quite successful to make a good regular expression.

Comment: I am not familiar with impala, but I found a [discussion about this issue](http://grokbase.com/t/cloudera/impala-user/143r2nr1hz/does-impala-support-different-timestamp-format), does this workaround help you: `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2000/01/01', 'yyyy/MM/dd')` ?

Comment: @Uooo Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I get "Bad date/time conversion format:" error with that.

Comment: And since your fields also contain time, can you try with `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(timestamp, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm')`?

Comment: Actually i tried that as well...

Comment: Actually your data is **not** in format `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM` but in format `M/d/yyyy H:m` with variable-length fields, which makes it a hell to parse. As you have just experienced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( timestamp, 'input_format' )) solution will work with Hive, but, for whatever reason, it does not work with Impala.  I would consider this a bug and recommend you submit it to Cloudera.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to use regexp_replace but was not quite successful to make
>   a good regular expression

What about regular expressions to extract individiual fields from your ugly date format, then good old *printf* to rebuild a consistent format?

```
select printf('%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%06d'
             , cast(regexp_extract('7/1/2014 0:24', '[0-9]+/[0-9]+/([0-9]+) [0-9]+:[0-9]+', 1) as int)
             , cast(regexp_extract('7/1/2014 0:24', '([0-9]+)/[0-9]+/[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+', 1) as int)
             , cast(regexp_extract('7/1/2014 0:24', '[0-9]+/([0-9]+)/[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+', 1) as int)
             , cast(regexp_extract('7/1/2014 0:24', '[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+ ([0-9]+):[0-9]+', 1) as int)
             , cast(regexp_extract('7/1/2014 0:24', '[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+ [0-9]+:([0-9]+)', 1) as int)
             , 0
             , 0 )
from DUAL limit 1
```

2014-07-01 00:24:00.000000